Compose Material Theme not giving the correct Color
I already setup custom color for Jetpack Compose theme, but when i call MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary it giving me the default purple color.
val primaryLight = Color(0xFF1F6A4E)

private val lightScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = primaryLight
)

@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> darkScheme
        else -> lightScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

And here's the usage:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            AppTheme{
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary))
            }
        }
    }
}



This is most likely due to the dynamic colors introduced in Android 12 (API level 31).
If you look at your theme you'll see that there are actually three cases in the when statement:

dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S
darkTheme
else

If dynamic colors are activated in the theme (dynamicColor) and the app currently runs on a device that supports dynamic colors (Build.VERSION_CODES.S) then it skips your explicitly defined lightScheme and darkScheme and uses a dynamic color palette instead.
You can try running your app on a device with API level of 30 or below to see the difference.
If you want to deactivate dynamic colors regardless of the API level so your lightScheme will always be used, then set the AppTheme's parameter accordingly:
AppTheme(dynamicColor = false) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
    )
}

Alternatively you can declare the parameter to be false by default or remove it (and the first when case) entirely.

Ah yes, sorry i kinda forgot about this since i usually turned off this variable. My apologies
